# Spring security setar o Token no Headers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cross-domain, microsserviços

Configurei o Cross para aceitar as requisição em AngularJS, mas, a resposta vem sem o token.
Como fazer para adicionar o token ao response?

Spring security:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers().cacheControl();

    http.csrf().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .cors()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/conectado").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/install/admin").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login/recuperarSenha").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    // We filter the api/login requests
    .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager(), getTokenAuthenticationService()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
    .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(getTokenAuthenticationService()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```